Installing Windscribe VPN
I am trying to install Windscribe VPN but I keep getting these errors.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of windscribe:
 windscribe depends on libopengl0; however:
  Package libopengl0 is not installed.
 windscribe depends on libxcb-cursor0; however:
  Package libxcb-cursor0 is not installed.

I tried sudo apt-get libopengl0 but it gives this error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopengl0 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.33-6 is to be installed
              Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.7.0-1) but 1.4.0-1 is to be installed



Did you follow, step-by-step, the guide at https://windscribe.com/guides/manual_ubuntu? 2. What Windscribe version do you have? Apparently, the latest is v. 2.8.6, per https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6982-windscribe.html 3. If all fails, see https://www.vpnranks.com/free-vpn/ubuntu/ for alternatives.


I am using Debian and I tried installing Windscribe version 2.9.9
